# Delphi - Duplicating Data between data sources

Tags: rest, delphi

Delphi Seattle, Win10.  I need to write a generic routine to refresh a set of tables from a single source to a single destination. The tables on both ends already exist, and the process is a complete refresh.... i.e. empty the destination table, and then copy all rows.  The tables are identical, same columns, datatypes etc.  The challenge is the restrictions of HOW to access the data.  The only access I have to the source is via REST. I can pull the data via REST, using RESTClient, RESTRequest, RESTResponse connected to RESTAdapter, TDataSource and TClientDataSet.  The destination is an Oracle database, which I have direct access to.

I have approx 15 tables, with the largest being approx 200,000 rows, 40 columns.

Right now, I am looping through each row, for each column on source, finding matching column in destination....  and the performance is killing me.  Is there a more elegant (and particularly faster) way to do this?

Here is a code snippet of what I am doing now...

```
// for each row, loop
...
// Copy Each Field
          for i := 0 to dm1.ds_Generic.DataSet.FieldCount - 1 do
          begin
            FieldFrom := dm1.ds_Generic.DataSet.Fields[i];
            FieldTo   := dm1.tGeneric.FindField(FieldFrom.FieldName);
            if Assigned(FieldTo) then
            begin
              FieldTo.Value := FieldFrom.Value;
            end;
          end;
```

Comment: Would you consider using FireDAC? It has a CopyDataSet method to do exactly that (and a bit more).

Comment: Don't use FindField for each field in each record.  Set up a lookup table of source and destination fields before the loop and use that instead of FindField.  Wrap a number of row insertions - say 10 or 20 - into the destination table in an explicit transaction and Commit it before going further.  Etc.

Comment: Also TDataSet has a CopyFields method.